# Metadata version mismatch for module /node_modules/time-ago-pipe/time-ago-pipe.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, package

I am using `time-ago-pipe version 1.3.2` with `angular 4.4`. But now to build for production, I receive the following error,

```
Metadata version mismatch for module /node_modules/time-ago-pipe/time-ago-pipe.d.ts,
found version 4, expected 3
```

Which version of this library will match with angular 4.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, for Angular 4.4, we need to include time-ago-pipe version 1.2.1. 
And for angular 5, we need to include version 1.3.2.